# Why does PyTorch mps throw "mismatched tensor types" on M2 Mac?

Tags: pytorch

I'm using an M2 Macbook Pro and can train the following network setting the device to "cpu"; however, when I set the device to "mps", nn/modules/conv.py throws the RuntimeError "Mismatched Tensor types in NNPack convolutionOutput".

Any ideas what I'm doing that might be causing this?

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mnist_nn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2,stride=2),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(9216, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25),
            nn.Linear(128, 10),
            nn.Softmax(dim=0)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        logits = self.mnist_nn(x)
        return logits
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I'm adding my main.py for completeness

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from NeuralNetwork import NeuralNetwork


DEVICE = "mps"
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-3
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 12


def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    # Set the model to training mode - important for batch normalization and dropout layers
    model.train()
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        # Compute prediction and loss
        X = X.to(DEVICE)
        y = y.to(DEVICE)
        pred = model(X)

        # This next line is throwing a SIGBUS
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), (batch + 1) * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")


def test_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn):
    # Set the model to evaluation mode - important for batch normalization and dropout layers
    model.eval()
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    num_batches = len(dataloader)
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0

    # Evaluating the model with torch.no_grad() ensures that no gradients are computed during test mode
    # also serves to reduce unnecessary gradient computations and memory usage for tensors with requires_grad=True
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            pred = model(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()
            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()

    test_loss /= num_batches
    correct /= size
    print(f"Test Error: \n Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    training_data = datasets.MNIST(root="data", train=True, download=True, transform=ToTensor())
    test_data = datasets.MNIST(root="data", train=False, download=True, transform=ToTensor())

    model = NeuralNetwork().to(DEVICE)
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

    for t in range(EPOCHS):
        print(f"Epoch {t + 1}\n-------------------------------")
        train_loop(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
        test_loop(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
```

Comment: Have you remembered to move the input tensor to the mps device? Can you show exactly how you "set the device to mps"?

Comment: I'm sure I didn't, now that you say that. How do I do that?

For my model, I do:
model = NeuralNetwork().to("mps")

But for my input tensor, I don't do anything. How do I move that to the mps device?

Comment: It's `some_tensor.to("mps")`

Comment: Thank you! It's now throwing a bus error in the call to CrossEntropyLoss() (the first time it calls it as loss_fn in train_loop().) I've edit my original post to include everything. Thank you for your help!